# Passing user-entered data to Queryset.filter() - is it safe?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a page which takes GET parameters from its url, and passes these directly to a REST API. So the page URL looks like:

```
foo.com/pizzas/?toppings=mushrooms&toppings=sausage
```

As the page loads, it will take the GET params and pass them to a REST API like:

```
foo.com/totally/unrelated/url/?toppings=mushrooms&toppings=sausage
```

On the backend, I want to extract these out and filter based on them. This is basically what I have right now:

```py
# inside a django rest framework ModelViewSet
#   it's not really relevant other than that self.request exists
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.model.objects.all()
    for param in self.request.query_params:
        # param = "toppings"
        if not self.is_real_model_field(param):  # assume this works
            continue
        param_value_list = self.request.query_params.getlist(param)
        # param_value_list = ['mushrooms', 'sausage']
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            f"{param}__in": param_value_list
        )
    return queryset
```

I've said that the fact it's Django Rest Framework is irrelevant, but I'm not 100% sure on that. In the above example, `request.query_params` is added by Django Rest Framework, but based on [DRF's documentation here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) I believe it is simply an alias for django's built-in `request.GET`.

So, is this safe to do in Django? A malicious actor could directly manipulate the URL. I assume that django's `QuerySet.filter(field__in: values)` will automatically do some cleaning for you, and/or the limited character set of a URL will help stop anything nasty from coming through, but I haven't been able to find any resources discussing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [django_filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-filter) package. It does what you want and you won't need to reinvent a wheel.

Using this package you could list all filterable fields. This package also adds query param value validation.

Comment: This does look pretty nice. I'm reading the docs now, trying to find out the answer to a followup question - 

Do you know if it supports foreign key relationships using something other than the primary key nicely? I am using UUIDs on the frontend, but because of the randomness, they don't index well, so my current solution is that the backend will convert UUIDs to the associated primary key before filtering on `foreign_key_field_id`.

Comment: Yes, you can do what ever you want with the values before filtering the queryset, simply use [method parameter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html?highlight=exclude#method).